# How to give background gradation like bar chart

Tags: android, gradient

If I want to make gradation in TextView like follow image, what I should do? Is there any idea or solution??

(The width-length of gradation is depending on the value of text in TextView)

[image]

Comment: just give `BackgroundColor` to `TextView` with your `Gradient`.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define drawable resource file like this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="180"
        android:endColor="@color/your_color"
        android:startColor="@color/your_color2"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

and use it as background of your view

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:background="@drawable/your_gradient"
        />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="30"
    android:id="@+id/percentageTextview"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

and on your activity use this

```
View background = (View) findViewById(R.id.view);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentageTextview);

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int  screenWidthInPix = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = background.getLayoutParams();
params.width = (screenWidthInPix * Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString()))/100;
background.setLayoutParams(params);
```